# Backbone.Marionette: Rendering two columns pseudotable with Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I want to render structure like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="table h-mb-10">
    <div class="table-cell">#{rendered cellview</div>
    <div class="table-cell">#{rendered cellview</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table h-mb-10">
    <div class="table-cell">#{rendered cellview</div>
    <div class="table-cell">#{rendered cellview</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I created two views described below:

```
class CellView extends Marionette.ItemView
  tagName: 'div'
  className: 'table-cell'

class TableCollectionView extends Marionette.CollectionView
  appendHtml: (collectionView, itemView, index)->
    if index % 2 is 0 
      @_lastRow = $('<div class="table h-mb-10"></div>')
      collectionView.$el.append(@_lastRow)
    @_lastRow.append(itemView.el)
  itemView: CellView
```

It works but when I reset a collection there are last some spare blocks. Something like this:

```
 <div>
      <div class="table h-mb-10"></div> <!-- spare -->
      <div class="table h-mb-10"></div> <!-- spare -->
      <div class="table h-mb-10">
        <div class="table-cell">#{rendered cellview}</div>
        <div class="table-cell">#{rendered cellview}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="table h-mb-10">
        <div class="table-cell">#{rendered cellview}</div>
        <div class="table-cell">#{rendered cellview}</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I can remove them on render, but it's kind of hack. Is there(in Marionette) idiomatic way to solve this issue?

Edit: it renders something like this

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Marionette.CompositeView` instead of `Marionette.CollectionView`. This will allow you to specify a template with 2 containers and overwrite `appendHtml` method to decide where to render an itemView (much like you do now).

One problem with overriding `appendHtml` is that you won't be able to take advantage of buffering when rendering collection ( ie. after reseting the collection ). This might be a problem if you have a lot of item there, since appending them one by one is quite slow.

Comment: There can be more than two containers

Comment: then just use your code, but have the collection view rerender itself on each reset.

Comment: To prevent adding containers on collection reset I use this code:
`onBeforeRender: function () {this.$el.empty()}`